# How do I access the text property of an Entry in MainPage.xaml to MainActivity.cs in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have written the UI in the shared project MainPage.xaml so that i need not design the UI for each android windows and ios. Now i want to write some android specific code where i need to access the Entry.text field in MainPage.xaml to MainActivity.cs. Is it possible to get the text property of a control in MainActivity.cs file?

MainPage.xaml code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PushTest.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->

        <Entry Placeholder="title"
               x:Name="titleTxt"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

        <Entry Placeholder="Message"
               x:Name="messageTxt"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>     

        <Button Text="Send Notification to A"
                Clicked="SendNotificationToA"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

I want to get the titleTxt in MainActivity.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the **MessagingCenter**

#### in MainPage

in button click event

```
private  void SendNotificationToA(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //...
   MessagingCenter.Send<Object, string>(this, "SendNotificationToA",titleTxt.Text );
}
```

#### in MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
          
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, string>(this, "SendNotificationToA", async (sender, arg) =>
    {
         //  arg is the text of entry , do something you want
    });

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Comment: will i be access all the controls on the MainPage.xaml using this method? I'm New to Xamarin. Please excuse.

Comment: Why did you want to access them in MainActivity ?

Comment: i am implementing firebase push notification, client to client. So its only for android ryt...I have written the UI in the sharing project. So i need to access the `titleTxt` and  `messageTxt` in the Main activity.cs to send it to the FCM server. I couldn't find any xamarin Forms implementation reference online. I finally got the reference to the same i wanted implemented using android studio (ref: below link) n now im converting it to Xamarin project.. https://blog.usejournal.com/send-device-to-device-push-notifications-without-server-side-code-238611c143

Comment: Yes , you can access all  the controls by using this method.

Comment: Thank you. Could u also write the code to get `messageTxt`  plz??

Comment: Just need to change the titleTxt.Text to messageTxt  .